# object detection with yolo - map

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I am working on an object detection project. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and yolov3 for object detection. I want to get map values of detection.
I write some different codes to terminal and run :

1.

```
./darknet detector map custom/project.data custom/yolov3-project.cfg custom/yolov3-project_final.weights
```

2.

```
 ./darknet detector map custom/project.data custom/yolov3-project.cfg custom/yolov3-project_final.weights -dont_show -ext_output<custom/train.txt>result.txt
```

3.

```
./darknet detector map custom/project.data custom/yolov3-project.cfg backup/yolov3-project_final.weights -points 101 -iou_thresh 0.5
```

they are running without any error but I could not get anything, my result.txt file is empty. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I am training on Yolov4 and get mAP value by the first command line as you show above. The reason may from your model does not valid, or has something wrong inside. I have met such case cause the model can load one layer only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command, it worked perfectly for me:

```
./darknet detector map data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg yolo-obj.weights -iou_thresh 0.5 > d:\map_result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you waint for complation of its next mAP values it will comeout as you can see in this picture.
[image]